# Installing windows optional features while offline

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

How can windows optional features be installed on a server that does not have internet access?

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-IPSecurity" -All
```

This works fine with most of the features, as I assume they are packaged (but not activated) with windows server 2016 (standard). Two features in particular fail to install as the server has no internet connection:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The source files could not be found. 
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are 
required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source 
location, see 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-NetFxExtensib ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

The error mentions using the -Source option to potentially specify a local source, but in the linked documentation I cannot find any reference as to how to actually acquire these source files individually to install from.

Are these files available? or do I have to build a image to use with DISM?

Comment: @Ramhound specifying `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-iis-netfxextensibility_.....` fails to find the source - I assume this is where it's looking for the source anyway? the only file in there is validcfg.dll

Comment: Related - https://serverfault.com/questions/614874/windows-feature-installation-fails-with-the-source-files-could-not-be-found

Comment: thankyou for the help, it appears that I needed to specify the version of the .net framework for the two packages I was having issues with (NetFxExtensibility & ASPNET), in this case IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 was what I was after

Comment: @Mjr - Wonderful I spent an hour writing an answer

Answer (score 1):

> The error mentions using the -Source option to potentially specify a source but in the linked documentation I cannot find any reference as to how to actually acquire these source files individually to install from.

You need to mount your Windows Server 2016 ISO.  **You need to use the correct index.** You should mount the ISO to a virtual drive the use that install.wim when you mount the image.

```
Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\test\images\myimage.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\test\offline
```

The following command will then use that mounted image to install the feature.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-IPSecurity -All -Source "c:\test\offline”
```

Sources

- [/Mount-Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#mount-image)
- [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps#examples)

Comment: This answer assumes the feature you want to install exists.  Be sure you use *Get-WindowsOptionalFeature* to get the proper feature name

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ramhound it turns out I just had the wrong name for the feature as i didn't specify the .net framework that it was based on/used

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it appears the two packages that were failing actually just needed the .NET framework version specified which is part of the feature name.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-NetFxExtensibility45" -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-ASPNET45" -All
```