# Install IIS Features on Windows offline without Powershell

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

As title.  I have a problem with this because the targer server with OS is Windows Server 2016 Standard and connected only with intranet not to outside for some reason.  That makes me unable to use the normal way to get it because of meeting the same error "Source file is not found."(translated from Traditional Chinese)

I've read [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1524397/installing-windows-optional-features-while-offline?newreg=dc73e9d3f3fe4042b713611344e44e9b) to try to solve my problem but I only have cmd.exe so I'm unable to use that `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` command.

Could someone guide me to solve this?

Comment: Why can’t you use the GUI to install the desired optional feature? You don’t specify the complete translated message but it sounds like someone removed the package from the WinSxS folder. If that’s the case you will have to mount the appropriate ISO and use the appropriate DISM command. You don’t need PowerShell, DISM, works with the command prompt.  Additionally, PowerShell 5.1 is built into Windows Server 2016 and it cannot be removed but you can prevent unprivileged users from opening a PowerShell session. Have an Administrator install the feature.